# Why registerForActivityResult always return the same result?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions

when I press switch first and second time request dialog show and press Do not allow the switch work normally.
But third time when I press switch the request dialog  not showing and I always get the value of isGranted as false

What should I do?
I want to create UI switch to enable/disable POST_NOTIFICATION

Is there any way of code to deny permission after user granted permission?.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

var mIsChecked = false
val permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
) { isGranted ->
    mIsChecked = isGranted
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        var isSwitchChecked by remember { mutableStateOf(mIsChecked) }
        MyComposeApplicationTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                Switch(
                    checked = isSwitchChecked,
                    onCheckedChange = {
                        if (it) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                                permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
                            }
                        } else {
                            isSwitchChecked = it
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only request Android runtime permissions a very limited amount of times.  If you see the system Dialog requesting the permission from the User once, or at most twice, the next time you call `permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)`, the OS will ignore that permission request, as you cannot spam such requests.

Moreover, the moment you grant a permission through a permission request, then any subsequent calls to `permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)` will simply return `granted` as a result.

Instead, what you should do is that you should keep track of the current permission state, and only surface the permission request whenever you intend for the User to grant it.

I would make the switch's state be equivalent to whatever you get out of `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`, and only request permissions with the intention of them granting them, and not with the intention of denying them.  Similarly, I don't recommend you attempt to create a flow to manually *deny* permissions, as this is not standard or recommended practice; Users can always go into your app's settings and turn off any unwanted permissions manually.

Lastly, I would also recommend you [read through their documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for a more in-depth explanation of how permissions work, and what the best practices are for permission request flows.

**UPDATE:**

As per your comment, there is a way for manually revoking runtime permissions that was added on Android 13 (SDK 33).

In your switch logic, you could add a call to [`Context.revokeSelfPermissionOnKill(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#revokeSelfPermissionOnKill(java.lang.String)) to revoke the permission that you want, but again, this will only work for devices running Android 13 or higher.  Make sure you read through [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#revokeSelfPermissionsOnKill(java.util.Collection%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) of how this function works carefully as well, because this process does not happen instantly, and instead will wait to revoke the given permission(s) until "it is safe to do so."

```
Switch(
    checked = isSwitchChecked,
    onCheckedChange = { checked ->
        if (checked) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                LocalContext.current.revokeSelfPermissionOnKill(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
            }
            isSwitchChecked = checked
        }
    }
)
```

However, I still don't think this is a good idea, and you should probably talk to whoever is asking you to do this because permissions are not meant to be revoked during runtime; the OS is simply not built like that, and this will inevitably have a bad *code smell* since it's basically going against the usual paradigm of permissions in Android development.

Comment: Is there any way of code to deny permission after user granted permission?. Because it is my project's requirement to create UI to enable/disable POST_NOTIFICATION permission.

Comment: Turns out that there is!  I'll quickly test what I found, and should then be updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: Answer has been updated @freeman

Comment: thank you so much @Iván Garza Bermea

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if this has helped you with you issue @freeman! Happy coding.